# Lightweight multiple-reader/single-writer queue implementation

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, message-queue, lock-free

I need a very simple multiple-reader/single-writer queue implementation for an small thread pool (equal to number of physical cores). For now I implemented it with condition variables, but I'm exploring lighter alternatives for a future version. I ended with something like this (C pseudo code):

```
#define QUEUE_MAXSIZE 16

struct queue {
  OS_WAIT_OBJECT writer_waitobj;
  OS_WAIT_OBJECT reader_waitobj;
  size_t head;
  size_t tail;
  int data[QUEUE_MAXSIZE];
};

/* Called by a single writer. */
void enqueue(struct queue* queue, int value)
{
  /* If queue is full wait to avoid overwriting. */
  while (queue->head - queue->tail == QUEUE_MAXSIZE) {
    OS_WAIT(queue->writer_waitobj);
  }

  /* There are a single writer so synchronization isn't necessary. */
  queue->data[queue->head] = value;
  queue->head++;

  /* If queue was empty, signal the new state to one reader. */
  if (queue->head == queue->tail) {
    OS_AWAKE_ONE(queue->reader_waitobj);
  }
}

/* Called by (few) multiple readers. */
int dequeue(struct queue* queue)
{
  int value;
  const size_t my_tail = tail;

  /* If queue is empty readers must wait. */
  while (queue->head == my_tail) {
    OS_WAIT(queue->reader_waitobj)
  }

  /* Spin-lock readers synchronization. */
  do {
    value = queue->data[my_tail];
  } while (!CPU_COMPARE_AND_SWAP(queue->tail, my_tail, my_tail+1));

  /* If queue was full, signal the new state to writer. */
  if (queue->head - my_tail == QUEUE_MAXSIZE) {
    OS_AWAKE_ONE(queue->writer_waitobj);
  }

  return value;
}
```

Is this implementation correct? Where is the fault? What lightweight wait-signal/awake-on-signal facilities provide the main OS (Linux, BSD, OS X, Windows)?

**Edit**

`OS_WAIT_OBJECT` is not forced to be a condition variable. It is a simple "go to sleep until scheduler awakes you because someone else sent a signal".

Comment: *Condition variables* normally requires lock(mutex) around their usage. Because of that your implementation have a little sence (CAS operations are not needed with mutex protection). Some OS have low level syncronization primitives, which are below of mutexes and conditional variables, so it is possible to use them directly for SPMC queue. E,g, Linux implements *futex*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I implemented my working queue with mutexes and condition variables. This one is not my working queue, it's an experimental one. OS_WAIT_OBJECT doesn't need to be a condition variable. Can be any other scheduler mechanism available by the OS.

Comment: Simple interpretation of OS_WAIT_OBJECT as `go to sleep until ...` is mostly useless: If signal is arived **after** the condition is checked but **before** calling this function, you will **wait with condition being true**. So given implementation cannot be correct *in general*. You need *wait*-mechanism with more complex semantic, but this semantic is OS-dependent.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If this checking and go-to-sleep is done in user space, yes, it can happen, but if it's done in kernel space I can't understand why it will happen. I have experience in embedded programming and my reasoning is that this mechanism can be implemented via `HALT` and `INT` machine instructions without problems. Can't the OS scheduler do a similar task?

Comment: The absence of the race between check and sleep within kernel code is provided by some sort of *critical section*. Corresponded critical section for user space is implemented mainly by *mutexes*, and *conditional variables* are used for wait inside them. This returns to your working implementation. So, what do you want exactly?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I want a lighter implementation more similar to what I'm used in embedded hardware. User space critical sections plus `HALT`-`INTERRUPT`-like OS scheduling. I don't understand why kernel needs a critical section. If it puts a thread to sleep with the signal flag set (the race condition you mention) is not a major problem if the scheduler checks this flag periodically and wake the thread on some future context switch event.

Comment: User space is not allowed to use powerful primitives like `HALT`, that is why critical sections are usually needed. However, as I said before, Linux provides *futex*-operations. Using one of these operations you may **ask** scheduler to move current thread to sleep **only if** value of some variable has some predefined value. Probably, you may adopt your implementation to use futexes. Note, that this implementation will be OS-dependent.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So I will check futex-operations. I only wanted to know if my implementation worth the time to do it. OS-specific is not a problem because is for internal use on Linux machines. Thank for your help.